# How to run services on startup in docker container

Tags: docker

I am using Centos7 in docker container. I have installed Rundeck in Centos.

How can i run rundeck automatically when centos boots up ?

In what manner do i need to edit .bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

To start an application inside a container at startup, set `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in your `Dockerfile`.

Example

```
FROM ...
RUN ...
EXPOSE ...
ENTRYPOINT ["<rundeck command>", "rundeck parameters"]
CMD ["my default rundeck options"]
```

Now you can start your container with the usual

```
docker run ... <image>
```

and it will start your rundeck application and pass along `rundeck parameters` and `my default rundeck options`. However, what's nice is that you can now also do

```
docker run ... <image> <special parameters>
```

Which results in your container starting the `rundeck` application with `rundeck parameters`, but the `my default rundeck options` are overridden by `special parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

Containerizing rundeck is not trivial because you would need several processes on the same container, including a relational database between them.

For that, the best practice is to configure supervisord to run and monitor such processes and set the dockerfile CMD to run it.

You can find an example of supervisord configuration for rundeck on this repo: https://github.com/jjethwa/rundeck